# trying to connect to socket admin panel but always getting io.disconnect or Invaild Namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

```
const { instrument } = require('@socket.io/admin-ui');
const { Server } = require('http')


//NOTE: I am only using node without express 
//SERVER CODE

const http = require('http').createServer((req, res) => {
  const headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://admin.socket.io",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS, POST, GET",
    "Access-Control-Max-Age": 2592000, // 30 days
  };

  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.writeHead(204, headers);
    res.end();
    return;
  }

  if (["GET", "POST"].indexOf(req.method) > -1) {
    res.writeHead(200, headers);
    res.end("Hello World");
    return;
  }

  res.writeHead(405, headers);
  res.end(`${req.method} is not allowed for the request.`);
})

const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
  cors: {origin: ["https://admin.socket.io", "http://127.0.0.1:5500"], credentials: true },
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(`a user connecd ${socket.id}`)



});

instrument(io, {auth: false})

http.listen(8080, () => console.log('listening on http://localhost:8080', http.address()))






const socket = io('ws://localhost:8080')
//CLIENT CODE

socket.on('connect', ()=>{
    console.log(`yuu are connect ${socket.id}`)
    
})
```

trying to connect the server to socket io admin panel but i get error invalid Namespace

and console:

to fix this issue, ensure that response to the preflight request for the private network resource has the Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network header set to true.

I have been stuck for a few days now